# Apache not rewriting url properly

Tags: windows, apache, proxypass

I am setting up a reverse proxy with apache for a program that uses kestrel.

I attempted in `httpd.conf`:

```
    <Location /asf>
    ProxyPass   http://localhost:1242/
    ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:1242/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^asf/$ http://localhost:1242/$1 [R=301,L]
    </Location>
```

and in `.htaccess`, placed in htdocs (root of site):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^asf/$ http://localhost:1242/$1 [R=301,L]
```

however neither of them has worked.

```
    <Location /asf>
    ProxyPass   http://localhost:1242/
    ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:1242/
    </Location>
```

by itself in `httpd.conf` works without problems, but however api requests do not make it to the desired location.

I expect requests sent to `example.com/asf/api/X` to go to `localhost:1242/api/X`.
In addition to this, `/api/NLog` is a websocket, if that matters.